# How do I order an MySQL by one of it's rows?

Tags: php, mysql

With a simple mysqli_query I retreive all tasks from my database. Every single task has a deadline. I want to calculate how many days are left for each single task. When that's done, I'd like to order all the tasks based on the days left. How can I achieve this? I have this simple piece of code getting all the tasks:

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tasks");
while($rows=mysqli_fetch_array($sql,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   $deadline = $rows['deadline'];
   $today = strtotime('now');
   $date_diff = $deadline - $today;

   echo $date_diff;
}
```

But how can I order them by $date_diff?

Comment: `SELECT t.*, DATEDIFF( day,t.deadline,CURDATE() ) AS DiffDate FROM tasks as t ORDER BY DATEDIFF( day,'deadline',CURDATE() )`

Comment: You sort results in SQL with `ORDER BY`. But do you actually want to show *all* tasks that exist in your table, even tasks fulfilled years ago? You may want to add a `WHERE` clause. There should be some status field in the table, so you can exclude finished tasks (as tasks that passed their deadline are not necessarily completed).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do that in you sql query.

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT TIMEDIFF(deadline, CURRENT_TIME) as date_diff FROM tasks ORDER BY TIMEDIFF(deadline, CURRENT_TIME)");
```

Comment: Why bother with the calculation in the sort? There's no difference between (ORDER BY x) and (ORDER BY x - constant) except the latter takes more time.

Comment: Yes, that is actually true, you can use "ORDER BY deadline" and that will return the same result a bit faster. Thank you for mentioning that.

Answer (score -1):

You can perform this minus operation in `mysql` and `ORDER BY` the same. Here is how you do it,

```
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM tasks ORDER BY (deadline-UNIX_TIMESTAMP())") DESC;
```

We've used [UNIX_TIMESTAMP()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) to get the current timestamp and deducting it from the deadline.

At the end of the query we've used `DESC` keyword which will sort the result by days left in descending order.